# How to do a reactive slider with quasar VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm using the component QSlider in order to sum multiple sliders while giving a maximum number of points that a user has to reach. For example : On one slider, I put two and the other one three, the total of 4 must not be exceeded. I have succeeded to block the number of the second slider at 2. The issue is that, although the number of the second slider is 2, visually I can continue to increase the value of my slider.

Is there someone who knows how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Code is available on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-kx4bfp?file=src/pages/IndexPage.vue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict the length of slider, you must set an `inner-max` value for it. 
In your case, it should be:

```
 <q-slider
            v-model="item.value"
            :min="0"
            :max="10"
            :inner-max="points + item.value"
            @update:model-value="calculatePoints(item.title)"
 />
```

***FYI***: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/slider#with-inner-min-max